# How to calculate the magnitude of rounding error in N-bit signed fixed-point arithmetic?

Tags: homework, fixed-point

In example take into consideration 11-bit `<11,5>` signed fixed-point arithmetic.

> 000000.11111 - 0.96875
>
> 000001.00000 - 1

so the error magnitude will be:

> (1 - 0.96875)/2 = 0.015625 ?